# most profitable way to operate wormhole "highway"

Tags: economy

> in the near morrows, mankind had gain the might of wormhole. for with this craft man could walk from a stead to another by only a gang of walk.
>
> such crafty man of that day was, that they are mayen themselves to build many and many of such wonders. that they build a link of doors, a highway of the world. one stead to another, one thede to another.a man could walk from far north to far and to far east and then to far west, with only a step of a door in his way.

My question : what would be the most profitable way to utilize this craft ?

for more context :

- the setting is near future with anglo saxonish aesthetic.
- the "door way" owners bund themselves in an association.
- the market target was the general populace
- their economy is similar to our. with stocks and all.
- the bund function as a trade guild. which seek to regulate who can make a doorway and the quality of each member doorway. no one shall make a doorway except a bund member.

Comment: What's of value in your marketplaces? Without context, this is an idea generating question and off-topic. Even with context, it'll be tough to ask the question in a way that's not asking for story-based answers.

Comment: Remarkable English-like arcane (medievalish ?) language.. what age is your story ? Could you add the technology-level please.. it would put your economy question in perspective.

Comment: the edit was made.

Comment: *"owners bund themselves in an association."* - Do the members of this association compete on an open market or are they a cartel monopolizing the wormhole technology? If the former, how easy is it for new companies to get into the wormhole business? If the latter, what circumstances allow them to maintain their monopoly and keep competition off the market? The answer to these questions would affect what business models are and are not feasible in your world. Can you answer them?

Comment: i edited the question again to add the demanded context.

Comment: Riddley Walker is that you?

Comment: This really needs a lot more information, such as how the doors are formed. It is one thing if the doors can only be created by a few with great technology, and in specific ares. But another thing entirely if Homeless Bob can open a door into a bank vault. Your question really REALLY needs a lot of development before it goes live.

Comment: @VogonPoet the edit states these gates can only be made by a organization named "bund". There's a membership. How corrupt these folks are we don't know, but I would not rule out crime entirely ! Agree this could use some data about the doors, when I was putting my answer I doubted about the first one (what's the max size ?)

Answer (score 2):

### Very convenient

Q: *"that they build a link of doors, a highway of the world. one stead to another, one thede to another"*

**Toll roads**

Highway indeed. Set up these gateways over roads. Let folks pay for passage, back and forth. The road would become very cheap and the yields would be  massive.

**Tourism**

Thousands of travelers would make use of these gates each holiday season. Very profitable activity and you'd need very little personnel. Places that are normally difficult to reach, you could set up a wormhole in camp #6 close to Mount Everests top.. you go 600m up and there you are, on top of the world.

**Escape prison and other criminal options**

Some of your bund members are criminals. A wormhole is sneaked into a prison and your kartel could free some very rich allies from prison. You also have wormhole criminals, last month they set up a wormhole inside a bank vault and transported all the money out.

Answer (score 1):

## Keep Earth hostage

If those earhlinfs don't pay you a million a day, one mouth of the hole ia going into the Sun. Let's see how they like it when the surface temperature is high enough to melt iron.